# SQLite - Limitation? Bug? Prepared Statements with HAVING clause

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a query that is run 1000s of times which I'm trying to optimize using prepared statements:

```
$query = "SELECT day, ticker, SUM(score*mod) as shares FROM indicators, modifiers WHERE indicators.dex=modifiers.dex AND ticker='$t' GROUP BY day, ticker HAVING shares>=$s";
```

When I run the query normally:

```
$transactions = $dbm->query($query);
```

I get the desired result set.

However, when I convert it into a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT day, ticker, SUM(score*mod) as shares FROM indicators, modifiers WHERE indicators.dex=modifiers.dex AND ticker=? GROUP BY day, ticker HAVING shares>=?");
```

and run:

```
$stmt->execute(array($t, 100));
```

it seems that it is unable to filter out the condition stated in the HAVING clause (so I get results where shares are less than 100).

Is this a bug / limitation to SQLite or am I doing something wrong?

All my other queries work fine when converted into prepared statements...

Comment: I also tried hardcoding the number of shares into the prepared statement and it worked fine. This only happens when its a variable.

Comment: yes, I'm using the pdo sqlite extension for sqlite3.

Comment: Try running these through EXPLAIN and see if sqlite generates same code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
$stmt->bindParam(2, $shares, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();